# why the thread pause when the other thread start in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, threadpool

I use a thread for update the ui and other thread for sending the message to socket like that

the imageButtonSwitch send a message to socket in a thread

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    .......

    imageButtonSwitch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (isConnect) {
                        if (isOpen) {
                            client.sendMsg("0x03");
                        } else {
                            client.sendMsg("0x01");
                        }
                    } else {
                        handler.post(new runnableUpdateConnectStatus(
                                "Please connect first!"));
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
    ......
    new Thread(new runnableUi()).start();
}
```

the runableUi update the view from the return of the socket

```
class runnableUi implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("ticktock..........");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(loopTime);

                if (isConnect) {
                    HashMap<String, Integer> r = client.sendMsg("0x00");

                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putSerializable("status", r);

                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.setData(extras);
                    msg.what = CB_UPDATEUI;
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);
                    System.out.println("uiui...");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("thread error...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is my socket class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SocketClient {
    static Socket client;
    private String returnData;

    public String getReturnData() {
        return returnData;
    }

    public void setReturnData(String returnData) {
        this.returnData = returnData;
    }

    public SocketClient(String site, int port) {
        try {
            client = new Socket(site, port);
            System.out.println("Client is created! site:" + site + " port:"
                    + port);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> sendMsg(String msg) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        // System.out.println("sendMsg  coming....");
        String result = "nothing:1";
        try {
            // BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
            // InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

            OutputStream outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
            byte st[] = new byte[1];
            if ("0x00".equals(msg)) {
                st[0] = 0x00; // get
            } else if ("0x01".equals(msg)) {
                st[0] = 0x01;
            } else if ("0x02".equals(msg)) {
                st[0] = 0x02;
            } else if ("0x03".equals(msg)) {
                st[0] = 0x03;
            } else {
                st[0] = 0x70;
            }
            outputStream.write(st);
            outputStream.flush();
            InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            // System.out.println(inputStream);
            try {
                // while (true) {
                int readSize = inputStream.read(buffer);
                //System.out.println(readSize);
                // Log.d(TAG, "readSize:" + readSize);
                // If Server is stopping
                if (readSize == -1) {
                    inputStream.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                }
                // if (readSize == 0)
                // continue;
                // Update the receive editText
                stringBuilder.append(new String(buffer, 0, readSize));

                result = stringBuilder.toString();
                // }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // out.println(msg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //System.out.println("sendMsg====msg:" + msg + ",result:" + result);
        m = Tools.getStatus(result);
        return m;
    }

    public void closeSocket() {
        try {
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        try {
            HashMap<String, Integer> result = sendMsg("0x00");

            if (result.get("FAN") >= 0) {
                return true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

I found the problem is that when I click the imageButtonSwitch. the `runnableUi` will stop loop. what's the problem with my code?

Comment: Is this the way to do multithreading in Andriod?

Comment: @ScaryWombat No, we usually don't use `Thread`, but `AsyncTask` instead. Also, we don't use `System.out.println`, but rather `Log.d(String)`.

Comment: Which phone are you using? How many cores does it have?

Comment: @Joffrey Didn't think so.  Would that cause his problem?

Comment: @AbhishekShukla I use the simulator for testing..

Comment: Try checking the value of this "Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()"

Comment: If you're going to do serious Android dev, you should really consider testing on real devices (much faster, and you feel interface problems better)

Comment: Do you have any error in the Logcat? how do you know the loop stops? Also, you're allocating a new `Thread` in each call to `onClick()`, you should probably declare your thread outside `onClick()`, and just call `start()` in `onClick()`.

Comment: @AbhishekShukla I use the Nexus7 for testing. same result.

Comment: @Joffrey no any error in the Logcat. and I can see what I println in the Logcat.. when I click the button, the println from `runableUi ` will stop.   ok let me try declare outside..

Comment: You can't `start()` a thread multiple times. So it does make sense to create a new `Thread` (or use a thread pool) on each click, if the client send should not block the UI thread.

Comment: Did you try using a debugger to find out exactly where and why runableUi is freezing? At this point, everyone is just speculating.  Do some real debugging, see what is really happening, stop making everyone guess what might be happening.

Comment: @RemyLebeau True, my mistake. But then it is one more reason not to use a thread, cause object allocation should be limited to what is necessary. And one only is needed here, an AsyncTask.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I found that if I　remove some code about the socket in `runnableUi`, the thread wouldn't freezing.

Comment: @chanjianyi: Then your socket code is likely not thread-safe, so when one thread performs `SendMsg()`, the other thread also performing `SendMsg()` gets blocked. What is `client` actually declared as?

Comment: Your socket class is not even remotely thread-safe.  And `sendMsg()` is doing a lot of work, both writing and reading. Think of what happens when multiple threads do that work at the same time on the same socket connection. They are going to overlap and corrupt your communications. If you are going to share a socket across threads, you have to synchronize access to it.